# How to use RN’s Fabric renderer with out of tree platforms

Tags: c++, reactjs, react-native

React Native's new renderer [Fabric](https://reactnative.dev/architecture/fabric-renderer) looks promising and improves interoperability with out of tree host platforms (built in c++). I have used React Native for mobile development and am familiar with creating new [native modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) for iOS and Android, but not adding a new platform itself. I'm familiar with UIManager, ViewManger, the bridge and changes with the new architecture (Turbo Modules, JSI etc). What I’m really curious about is using Fabric renderer with a new host platform.

Say I have a C++ project that uses a windowing library like GTK+ or Qt, how could I use the Fabric renderer and React Native as my UI layer?

I Understand this is a broader question but I haven’t been able to find any docs around adding a new host to RN in two weeks of searching. Any pointers/ resources would greatly be appreciated.

The [official docs for adding a platform](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) are not very helpful, just looking for a more comprehensive overview.

So far I’ve looked at the out of tree projects referenced in the docs and [this project](https://github.com/valence-native/valence-native) has been helpful, but uses Node bindings for the upstream windowing lib where I am trying to use Fabric to interface with my c++ code.